# Swift String hasPrefix Using an Array of Strings

Tags: swift

I want to avoid the `if` statement in the sample code below, and instead make a single call to `hasPrefix` on my number string and pass in the `prefixes` array.  Is there a way to do this in Swift?

```
let prefixes: [String] = ["212", "213", "214"]
let number: String = "213-555-1212"

if number.hasPrefix("212") || number.hasPrefix("213") {
    print("found")
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is in @vacawama's comment `prefixes.contains(where: number.hasPrefix)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I moved it to an answer since the other poster seems unwilling to incorporate constructive feedback.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done succinctly with:

```
if prefixes.contains(where: number.hasPrefix) {
    print("found")
}
```

**So, how does this work?**

1. `contains(where:)` takes a closure that gets called for each element of the `prefixes` array to decide if the element matches the desired condition.  Since `prefixes` is an array of `String`, that closure has the signature `(String) -> Bool`, meaning it takes a `String` and returns a `Bool`.  `contains(where:)` will continue to call the given closure for each element in the `prefixes` array until it gets a `true` returned, or until it runs out of items in the `prefixes` array, at which time the answer is `false` (`prefixes` doesn't contain an item that matches the condition).
2. In this case, we are passing the function `number.hasPrefix` as the closure.  Normally you'd use `number.hasPrefix` by calling it with an argument like this: `number.hasPrefix("212")`.  Without the argument, `number.hasPrefix` refers to the function `hasPrefix` called on `number` and that function has the signature we're looking for: `(String) -> Bool`. So it can be used as the closure for `contains(where:)`.
3. So, `prefixes.contains(where: number.hasPrefix)` takes each `prefix` from the array and checks if `number.hasPrefix(prefix)` returns `true`.  If it finds one, it stops searching and returns `true`.  If all of them return `false`, then `prefixes.contains(where:)` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
prefixes.forEach { prefix in
    if number.hasPrefix(prefix) {
        print("found")
    }
}
```

You might want to make sure that the `prefixes` array has no duplicates (= is effectively a set).

Answer (score 0):

If readability is important, you might try this:

```
extension String {
    func hasAnyPrefix(_ prefixes: [String]) -> Bool {
        return prefixes.contains { self.hasPrefix($0) }
    }
}

if number.hasAnyPrefix(prefixes) {
    print("found")
}
```